# discord.py Bot which searches and sends files

Tags: python

Im coding an bot which searches and sends files search command is already infuction but send command won't work here is my code appreciate any help

```
@bot.command()
async def search(ctx, *, file_name):
    search_result = ''
    from os import listdir
    for file in listdir('ArkFiles/Dinos'):
        if file_name in file.lower():
            search_result = search_result+'\n'+file
    if search_result == 'Search Results:':
        await ctx.reply('Error: Not matched with any file.')
    else:
         embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Here is a list of  files I found in the current Ark files that include '{file_name}':")
         embed.add_field(name='** **', value= search_result, inline=False)
         await ctx.reply(embed=embed)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def sendachatina(ctx):
    area=ctx.message.channel
    await bot.send_file(area, "ArkFiles/Dinos/Achatina.zip", filename="Achatina.zip",content="Here you go:")
```

I don't want it that i have to do a command for every single file i want it that i have to input correctly and it automatically outputs the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to send the file by your style of coding but follow the below code it works for sure

```py
await ctx.send(file=discord.File("ArkFiles/Dinos/Achatina.zip"),content="Here you go:")
```

This is the syntax of the send in discord.py. There is no option to change file there

```py
await ctx.send(content=None, *, wait=False, username=None, avatar_url=None, tts=False, file=None, files=None, embed=None, embeds=None, allowed_mentions=None)
```

where

```sh
content (str) – The content of the message to send.

wait (bool) – Whether the server should wait before sending a response. This essentially means that the return type of this function changes from None to a WebhookMessage if set to True.

username (str) – The username to send with this message. If no username is provided then the default username for the webhook is used.

avatar_url (Union[str, Asset]) – The avatar URL to send with this message. If no avatar URL is provided then the default avatar for the webhook is used.

tts (bool) – Indicates if the message should be sent using text-to-speech.

file (File) – The file to upload. This cannot be mixed with files parameter.

files (List[File]) – A list of files to send with the content. This cannot be mixed with the file parameter.

embed (Embed) – The rich embed for the content to send. This cannot be mixed with embeds parameter.

embeds (List[Embed]) – A list of embeds to send with the content. Maximum of 10. This cannot be mixed with the embed parameter.

allowed_mentions (AllowedMentions) – Controls the mentions being processed in this message.
```

This is the documentation of discord.py if you want you can refer it
[here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_file)